# Firebase Cloud Function not triggering on different app's Realtime Database

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions, hacker-news-api

I'm trying to [trigger a Firebase Cloud Function on a Realtime Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events) owned by a different app: the [Hacker News API](https://github.com/HackerNews/API). I'm passing `databaseUrl: https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/` to `admin.initializeApp()`, and it deploys fine, but it never triggers, even though new items in this RTDB are regularly getting created.

```js
const functions = require('firebase-functions')
const admin = require('firebase-admin')
admin.initializeApp({databaseUrl: 'https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/'})

exports.itemUpdated = functions.database.ref('/v0/item/{id}').onCreate((snapshot, context) => {
      functions.logger.log('Item: ', context.params.id, snapshot.val())
      return null
})
```

I've tried it without `databaseUrl` in the local emulator, and it works fine. I've also tried a number of variations, eg `functions.database.instance('hacker-news')` and `databaseUrl: 'https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0'`, but no luck, it never triggers in production. Any idea what I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just not possible to write functions in one project for a database in another project.  The events generated from database changes always stay within the project.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! And, disappointing! Maybe consider raising an error in this case, ie when databaseUrl is in a different project, to avoid confusion?

Comment: I no longer work for Google. The best way to propose this is to post an issue on GitHub. https://github.com/firebase/firebase-functions